# Vertically Aligning Child Elements

Tags: html, css, haml, vertical-alignment, navbar

I'm trying to vertically align the elements in a navbar on my homepage.  Inside the div is an ul, which has li with a tags in them like to.  So far vertical align hasn't really worked.  Here's the HAML:

```
.navcontainer
  %div#middle
    %ul#nav
      %li
        = link_to 'About', '#'
      %li#signup
        = link_to 'Sign Up', '#', :id => "signup"
        = render 'devise/registrations/new'
      %li#login
        = link_to 'Login', '#', :id =>'login'
        = render 'devise/sessions/new'
```

And here's the associated CSS, ahem, SASS:

```
// Nav Bar
.navcontainer{
  width: 100%;
  background: $gray;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;

  ul li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    a{
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      float: left;
      font-family: Domine;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 25px;
      padding-left: 15px; 
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
      &:visited{
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      &:hover{ 
        color: $hovercolor;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
      }
    }
  }
}

// RegistrationFields and Partials
.registration{
  display: inline-block;
  #new_user{

    input {
    border-radius: 10px;
    height:26px !important;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    border:none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px; 
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Any chance you can set up a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: btw, that's not "css"

Comment: @user1737909, what isn't CSS?

Comment: Just coming back to this and it works, thanks Derek!

Comment: nots sure why there's so much downvoting though

Comment: @KeithJohnson, I assumed you were doing all the downvoting, so I just deleted my post.

Comment: if you put it back up there i'll accept it as correct

Answer (score -1):

If your navigation bar is a fixed height, try the following:

```
.navcontainer div ul {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

obviously alter the size depending on the height of the bar.

Answer (score -1):

Try `postition:relative` On the parent div / wrapper. Then add `position:relative` to the child element. You should then be able to add top:0px. This will align the child element to the top of the relative wrapper.

Hope this helps.